# CSS Page transitions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am wondering how to approach page transitions, as I am quite new to them.

I would like to add random transition out of these, used in this demo on codrops: https://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/05/07/a-collection-of-page-transitions/

The thing is, the tutorials I have watched on youtube, are all using just one .html file. My structure is somewhat different, having multiple .html files (contact, gallery) etc. and one css style

Here's my html file. I tried following the steps on codrops, but I ended up with white screen. Anyone got any experience with this ?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Style.css"/>
      <title>Untitled Document</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
         <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
         <a href="Index.html">Domov</a>
         <a href="Gallery.html">Galéria</a>
         <a href="Contact.html">Kontakt</a>
         <a href="Aboutme.html">O mne</a>
      </div>
      <script>
         /* Set the width of the side navigation to 250px */
         function openNav() {
            document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
         }

         /* Set the width of the side navigation to 0 */
         function closeNav() {
            document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
         }


      </script>
      <div id="first">
         <ul>
            <li><a href="#" id="up" onClick="openNav()" >Menu</a></li>
         </ul>
         <div id="block">
            <h2>Filip Ducký</h2>
            <p id="desc">Portfoilo</p>
            <br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
            <a href="#" class="tlacitko">Moje Práce</a>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div id="second">
         <section>
            <img src="Img/Info.png" class="info" alt="">
            <h3>Grafik</h3>
            <p class="info2">Lorem Ipsum je fiktívny text, používaný pri návrhu tlačovín a typografie. Lorem Ipsum je štandardným výplňovým textom už od 16. storočia, keď neznámy tlačiar zobral sadzobnicu plnú tlačových znakov a pomiešal ich, aby tak vytvoril vzorkovú knihu. Prežil nielen päť storočí, ale aj skok do elektronickej sadzby, a pritom zostal v podstate nezmenený. Spopularizovaný bol v 60-tych rokoch 20.storočia, vydaním hárkov Letraset, ktoré obsahovali pasáže Lorem Ipsum, a neskôr aj publikačným softvérom ako Aldus PageMaker, ktorý obsahoval verzie Lorem Ipsum.</p>
         </section>
         <section>
            <img src="Img/Info.png" class="info" alt="">
            <h3>Webové stránky</h3>
            <p class="info2">Lorem Ipsum je fiktívny text, používaný pri návrhu tlačovín a typografie. Lorem Ipsum je štandardným výplňovým textom už od 16. storočia, keď neznámy tlačiar zobral sadzobnicu plnú tlačových znakov a pomiešal ich, aby tak vytvoril vzorkovú knihu. Prežil nielen päť storočí, ale aj skok do elektronickej sadzby, a pritom zostal v podstate nezmenený. Spopularizovaný bol v 60-tych rokoch 20.storočia, vydaním hárkov Letraset, ktoré obsahovali pasáže Lorem Ipsum, a neskôr aj publikačným softvérom ako Aldus PageMaker, ktorý obsahoval verzie Lorem Ipsum.</p>
         </section>
         <section>
            <img src="Img/Info.png" class="info" alt="">
            <h3>3D</h3>
            <p class="info2">Lorem Ipsum je fiktívny text, používaný pri návrhu tlačovín a typografie. Lorem Ipsum je štandardným výplňovým textom už od 16. storočia, keď neznámy tlačiar zobral sadzobnicu plnú tlačových znakov a pomiešal ich, aby tak vytvoril vzorkovú knihu. Prežil nielen päť storočí, ale aj skok do elektronickej sadzby, a pritom zostal v podstate nezmenený. Spopularizovaný bol v 60-tych rokoch 20.storočia, vydaním hárkov Letraset, ktoré obsahovali pasáže Lorem Ipsum, a neskôr aj publikačným softvérom ako Aldus PageMaker, ktorý obsahoval verzie Lorem Ipsum.</p>
         </section>
      </div>
      <div id="third">
         <div class="am1">
            <img src="Img/Info_dark.png" class="am2" alt="">
            <h3 id="omne">O mne</h3>
            <p class="am3">Lorem Ipsum je fiktívny text, používaný pri návrhu tlačovín a typografie. Lorem Ipsum je štandardným výplňovým textom už od 16. storočia, keď neznámy tlačiar zobral sadzobnicu plnú tlačových znakov a pomiešal ich, aby tak vytvoril vzorkovú knihu. Prežil nielen päť storočí, ale aj skok do elektronickej sadzby, a pritom zostal v podstate nezmenený. Spopularizovaný bol v 60-tych rokoch 20.storočia, vydaním hárkov Letraset, ktoré obsahovali pasáže Lorem Ipsum, a neskôr aj publikačným softvérom ako Aldus PageMaker, ktorý obsahoval verzie Lorem Ipsum.</p>
         </div>
         <br><br><br>
         <a href="#" class="tlacitko2">Kontakt</a>
         <br><br><br><br>
      </div>
      <footer>
         <div id="left">
            <p id="fot"> © 2017</p>
         </div>
         <div id="right"><a href="#up"><img id="arrow" src="Img/arrow.png" alt=""></a></div>
      </footer>
   </body>
</html>
```

I would like to make transitions between pages. Home - gallery, gallery - contact, etc. My apologies if this wasn't clear from the post.

Comment: It is not possible to transition between multiple html-files. Both container you want to transition have to be in the same html-file. Advanced mode: you could load the new page with ajax and inject it into a container in the current page.

Comment: Oh well, thank you for letting me know that.

Comment: Wil this be an option? ... Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16289964/how-to-add-transition-when-loading-a-web-page

Answer (score 0):

Try following CSS:

```
#mySidenav{
    transition: all 500ms;
}
```

Here is the quick format for `transition`

`transition: <Properties to apply on> <duration>;`

`duration` can be in `ms` or in `s`

Check the following snippet:

```css
#mySidenav {
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background: white;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 500ms;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Style.css" />
  <title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
    <a href="Index.html">Domov</a>
    <a href="Gallery.html">Galéria</a>
    <a href="Contact.html">Kontakt</a>
    <a href="Aboutme.html">O mne</a>
  </div>
  <script>
    /* Set the width of the side navigation to 250px */
    function openNav() {
      document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
    }

    /* Set the width of the side navigation to 0 */
    function closeNav() {
      document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
    }
  </script>
  <div id="first">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#" id="up" onClick="openNav()">Menu</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="block">
      <h2>Filip Ducký</h2>
      <p id="desc">Portfoilo</p>
      <br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
      <a href="#" class="tlacitko">Moje Práce</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="second">
    <section>
      <img src="Img/Info.png" class="info" alt="">
      <h3>Grafik</h3>
      <p class="info2">Lorem Ipsum je fiktívny text, používaný pri návrhu tlačovín a typografie. Lorem Ipsum je štandardným výplňovým textom už od 16. storočia, keď neznámy tlačiar zobral sadzobnicu plnú tlačových znakov a pomiešal ich, aby tak vytvoril vzorkovú knihu.
        Prežil nielen päť storočí, ale aj skok do elektronickej sadzby, a pritom zostal v podstate nezmenený. Spopularizovaný bol v 60-tych rokoch 20.storočia, vydaním hárkov Letraset, ktoré obsahovali pasáže Lorem Ipsum, a neskôr aj publikačným softvérom
        ako Aldus PageMaker, ktorý obsahoval verzie Lorem Ipsum.</p>
    </section>
    <section>
      <img src="Img/Info.png" class="info" alt="">
      <h3>Webové stránky</h3>
      <p class="info2">Lorem Ipsum je fiktívny text, používaný pri návrhu tlačovín a typografie. Lorem Ipsum je štandardným výplňovým textom už od 16. storočia, keď neznámy tlačiar zobral sadzobnicu plnú tlačových znakov a pomiešal ich, aby tak vytvoril vzorkovú knihu.
        Prežil nielen päť storočí, ale aj skok do elektronickej sadzby, a pritom zostal v podstate nezmenený. Spopularizovaný bol v 60-tych rokoch 20.storočia, vydaním hárkov Letraset, ktoré obsahovali pasáže Lorem Ipsum, a neskôr aj publikačným softvérom
        ako Aldus PageMaker, ktorý obsahoval verzie Lorem Ipsum.</p>
    </section>
    <section>
      <img src="Img/Info.png" class="info" alt="">
      <h3>3D</h3>
      <p class="info2">Lorem Ipsum je fiktívny text, používaný pri návrhu tlačovín a typografie. Lorem Ipsum je štandardným výplňovým textom už od 16. storočia, keď neznámy tlačiar zobral sadzobnicu plnú tlačových znakov a pomiešal ich, aby tak vytvoril vzorkovú knihu.
        Prežil nielen päť storočí, ale aj skok do elektronickej sadzby, a pritom zostal v podstate nezmenený. Spopularizovaný bol v 60-tych rokoch 20.storočia, vydaním hárkov Letraset, ktoré obsahovali pasáže Lorem Ipsum, a neskôr aj publikačným softvérom
        ako Aldus PageMaker, ktorý obsahoval verzie Lorem Ipsum.</p>
    </section>
  </div>
  <div id="third">
    <div class="am1">
      <img src="Img/Info_dark.png" class="am2" alt="">
      <h3 id="omne">O mne</h3>
      <p class="am3">Lorem Ipsum je fiktívny text, používaný pri návrhu tlačovín a typografie. Lorem Ipsum je štandardným výplňovým textom už od 16. storočia, keď neznámy tlačiar zobral sadzobnicu plnú tlačových znakov a pomiešal ich, aby tak vytvoril vzorkovú knihu.
        Prežil nielen päť storočí, ale aj skok do elektronickej sadzby, a pritom zostal v podstate nezmenený. Spopularizovaný bol v 60-tych rokoch 20.storočia, vydaním hárkov Letraset, ktoré obsahovali pasáže Lorem Ipsum, a neskôr aj publikačným softvérom
        ako Aldus PageMaker, ktorý obsahoval verzie Lorem Ipsum.</p>
    </div>
    <br><br><br>
    <a href="#" class="tlacitko2">Kontakt</a>
    <br><br><br><br>
  </div>
  <footer>
    <div id="left">
      <p id="fot"> © 2017</p>
    </div>
    <div id="right">
      <a href="#up"><img id="arrow" src="Img/arrow.png" alt=""></a>
    </div>
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```